# post method in API not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, api

I have a simple api method to insert data to db, the method in postman man is showing success, but the data is not inserted in database, here is my code

```
private Utilities uti = new Utilities();
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext db;
    public AppraisalController(ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    //INSERT API FOR AppraisalIdentity table
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/appraiseinsert")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] AppraisalIdentity cre)
    {
        if (cre == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                #region Appraisal Insert
                var apprais = new AppraisalIdentity
                {
                    AppraisalName = cre.AppraisalName,
                    IsCurrent = cre.IsCurrent,
                    CompanyID = cre.CompanyID,
                    DateAdded = cre.DateAdded
                };
                db.AppraisalIdentity.Add(apprais);
                db.SaveChanges();
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                return Json(new
                {
                    statusCode = ex.Message
                });
            }

        }

        return Json(new
        {
            statusCode = "Success"
        });
    }
```

I don't know, maybe there's an error somewhere in my code that I don't know about, but the fact is that in postman, the api is returning success, but its not inserting anything in db. Thanks

Comment: You don't really need a transaction anyway. [In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a transaction i guess you need to commit the transaction after calling db.SaveChanges() like this:

```
db.SaveChanges();
transaction.Commit();
```